# how to create fragments using Annotations of spring-spqr graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter graphQL

Tags: java, graphql-java, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

using *graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter* and *graphql-spqr* but not able to create Fragment using @GraphQLDirective, not sure if there is anyway to do it.

my intension is to create Fragment through code like

```
@Data
@GraphQLFragment
public class ProfileFields{
 private String name;
 private String emailId;
 private String phoneNo;
}
```

and use this fragment in the query below, can someone guide me what are the annotations used for this

```
{
  profile(id: "101"){
    ...ProfileFields
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how GraphQL works. Fragments are defined **by the client** ad-hoc. You can not define them ahead of time on the server. The definition of the fragment is a part of the query. There's nothing you need to (or can) do on the server for the fragments to work.

The client could send a query such as:

```
{
  profile(id: "101") {
    ... ProfileFields
  }
}

fragment ProfileFields on Profile {
  name
  registrationDate
}
```

As for `@GraphQLDirective`, it is used to define schema (server-side) directives. Directives are not related to fragments.

Comment: thanks @kaqqao my question is how can we get the fragments done using GraphQL SPQR, can you help me find the answer please.